# How To stop batch?

Tags: batch-file, sql-job

I have scheduled a sql job which triggers a batch file.
Batch is calling a package

Even if I stop job from SQL job agent,  batch continues to execute that package

how can i stop that batch being processed ?

Comment: `how can i stop that batch being processed ?` Delete it. Or rename it. Or remove it from the sql job.

Comment: You could start helping yourself, by providing sufficient information to create an on topic question. Please refresh your mind by taking the [tour] and reading [ask], before [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54309474/edit) as necessary.

Comment: I'm stopping a job in a middle but it keeps running. Because of batch . I think deleting would not help in this case

Comment: Please follow the advice provided in my previous comment, without it, you're relying on responder's guesses.